# Keeping track of object id in Django view

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-forms

My view is a function based view (it is a legacy and due to inline formset usage it is easier to keep it that way, rather than CBV). My goal is to be able to render the ModelForm for the model object  Article.objects.get(user=user).latest("id") and with the POST method, update the same object that has been rendered. The issue is that the ModelForm "does not remember" the object it corresponded to. What would be the right way to pass that info about the object to the view for use in the POST method?

Below is the simplified version of the views.py and the urls.py

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from specify.models import Article
from specify.forms import ArticleForm

def index(request):

    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

    if request.method == "POST":
        a_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance= *???* )
        a_form.save()
    else:
        a = Article.objects.get(user=user).latest("id")
        a_form = ArticleForm(instance=a)

    return render_to_response(
        "specify/index.html",
        {
            "a_form" : a_form,
        }, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from specify import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

EDIT1: added models.py and forms.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from specify.models import Article

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content']
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do here `a_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance= *???* )`? You want to save it to db?

Comment: Ok I understand can you publish your model and ArticalForm definition here?

Comment: @Phoenix: Just added models.py and forms.py. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should pass article id to the template, in view.py

```
def index(request):

user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

if request.method == "POST":
     #Explained later 
else:
    a = Article.objects.get(user=user).latest("id")
    a_form = ArticleForm(instance=a)
    article_id = a.id   

return render_to_response(
    "specify/index.html",
    {
        "a_form" : a_form,
        "article_id": article_id,
    }, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Second in your template inside of your form html element you should handle your article id

```
{% if article_id %}
<input type="hidden" value='{{ article_id }}' id='article_id' name='article_id'/>
{% endif %}
```

Thirdly in update handling you should do following:

```
if request.method == "POST":            
    article_id = request.POST.get('article_id') # You are getting passed article id
    a = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)      # You are getting instance by id
    a_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
    a_form.save()
```

Try above steps and if you have problem leave a comment

Comment: Thanks. Just before I try it: in the template, should article_id be a part of the form/formset that is being submitted? Or otherwise, how is it get submitted?

Comment: it should be inside of form. It will be submitted automatically